# How to improve this seaborn countplot?

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I used the following code to generate the countplot in python using seaborn:

```
sns.countplot( x='Genres', data=gn_s)
```

But I got the following output:

[image: output]

I can't see the items on x-axis clearly as they are overlapping. How can I correct that?
Also I would like all the items to be arranged in a decreasing order of count. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use choose the `x-axis` to be vertical, as an example:

```
g = sns.countplot( x='Genres', data=gn_s)
g.set_xticklabels(g.get_xticklabels(),rotation=90)
```

Or, you can also do:

```
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
```

Comment: I am getting the following error: set_xticklabels() missing 1 required positional argument: 'labels'

Comment: Thanks I got the labels flipped. Any hint on how to arrange it a increasing/decreasing order?

Comment: You can use the `order` parameter in `sns.countplot`, as an example, `sns.countplot( x='Genres', data=gn_s, order = gn_s['Genres'].value_counts().index)`

Comment: You can read about [seaborn.countplot parameters](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.countplot.html).

Answer (score 1):

Bring in matplotlib to set up an axis ahead of time, so that you can modify the axis tick labels by rotating them 90 degrees and/or changing font size. To arrange your samples in order, you need to modify the source. I assume you're starting with a pandas dataframe, so something like:

`data = data.sort_values(by='Genres', ascending=False)
labels =  # list of labels in the correct order, probably your data.index
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(1,1)
sns.countplot( x='Genres', data=gn_s, ax=ax1)
ax1.set_xticklabels(labels, rotation=90)`

would probably help.

*edit* Taking [andrewnagyeb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7347631/andrewnagyeb)'s suggestion from the comments to order the plot:

`sns.countplot( x='Genres', data=gn_s, order = gn_s['Genres'].value_counts().index)`

Comment: Thanks that worked partially, the labels are flipped vertically. But I still don't have them in decreasing order since it is a count plot. It is counting how many times a particular word is appearing and finally plotting the results.