# How to add counts and remove top and right spines of a countplot?

Tags: python, seaborn

How can I improve this graph by adding the count on the top of each bar and retrieving the lines on the top and on the right (just keeping the x and y axis)? In a "flexible" way (I mean, not just for this graph, but easily to replicate with another data)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris

iris = load_iris()
df = pd.DataFrame(data= np.c_[iris['data'], iris['target']],
                 columns= iris['feature_names'] + ['target'])
sns.countplot(df['target']);
```

I tried looking at some posts, like [How to improve this seaborn countplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48043365/how-to-improve-this-seaborn-countplot), and even at the documentation (https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.countplot.html), but I couldn't find a these things.

Comment: Similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31754317/12046409), but leaving out the division by `total`

Comment: To remove the spines: [How can I remove the top and right axis in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/925024/how-can-i-remove-the-top-and-right-axis-in-matplotlib)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, Try:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris

iris = load_iris()
df = pd.DataFrame(data= np.c_[iris['data'], iris['target']],
                 columns= iris['feature_names'] + ['target'])
ax = sns.countplot(df['target']);
for p in ax.patches:
    height = p.get_height()
    ax.text(p.get_x()+p.get_width()/2.,
            height + 3,
            f'{p.get_height()}',
            ha="center") 
    
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Where does this 'height' comes from? I tried running the script and it didin't recognize this variable

Comment: @DumbML Oops.  I removed a line by accident.  Updated answer.

Comment: Great, many thanks! Just one more thing, if it's not too much, how can I increase the size of the bar labels? How can I make 50 greater? plt.xticks?

Comment: Try: `ax.tick_params(axis='x', labelsize=50)`

Comment: Actually, that only worked for the x-label. But the "50" above the bar are still very small here

Comment: `ax.text(p.get_x()+p.get_width()/2.,
            height + 3,
            f'{p.get_height()}',
            ha="center", fontsize=50)` add fontsize parameter to ax.text method.